# Why working directory is changing when executing Invoke-sqlcmd?

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012

I am trying to search whether particualr machine name is there in database and if so we are replacing with new machine name.

We are using powershell

```
 Add-pssnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Add-pssnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $SelectQuery = "SELECT [$columnName] FROM [$DatabaseName].[dbo].[$TableName] Where [$columnName] is not null;"

    try {
          $Qresult= Invoke-sqlcmd -query $SelectQuery -Database $DatabaseName -ServerInstance $srvInstance -Verbose
          $Qresult = $Qresult| % { $_.$columnName+"`n" 

           #check whether the Machine Name is found if the column value is processed in URL format
            $IsOldFoundFromURL=TestOldMachineFromURL $Qresult $OldMachineName

            #check whether the Machine Name is found if the column value is processed in Connection string format
            $IsOldFoundFromConn=TestOldMachineFromconnstring $Qresult $OldMachineName

            If ( $IsOldFoundFromURL -or  $IsOldFoundFromConn ) {

                    LogWrite "Columns Name before changing: $columnName "
                    LogWrite "$Qresult"
            }
            Else {
                    LogWrite "OldMachine name is not found in DB"
                    Return
            }
     }
     catch {
            Write-error "Error occured when executing sql $SelectQuery"
            LogWrite $Error[0]
        }
```

Every thing works fine . But when executing Invoke-sqlcmd the drive letter is changing to SQLServer:\ which is surprising.

I am running this in Windows 2012 R2 machine and executing this against sQL server 2012.

The problem is when the working directory is changing our script fails as we are writting a log file in current script path, when the script path changes to SQLserver:\ ,unable to create log file and fails.

Comment: That code doesn't look complete. At what point are you doing the write to the log?

Comment: So it fails when trying to write to the log, but you've not included the `LogWrite` function where that actually happens. Surely that's the most relevant part of the script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue occurs as part of running the `Add-pssnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` section of your code at the start. I'm not sure why it does this but I know that when I run a similar command (`Import-Module 'sqlps' -DisableNameChecking`) on computers in our network running MS SQL 2012, it changes the filesystem location from whatever location to the `SQLSERVER:>` location - I assume this is because it expects you to begin using commands in the SQL Server instance.

To overcome this problem, you can do a `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` command to move back to your original location, like so;

```
C:\Users\foo.bar> Push-Location
C:\Users\foo.bar> Add-pssnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
SQLSERVER:\> Add-pssnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
SQLSERVER:\> Pop-Location
C:\Users\foo.bar> _
```

Either that or overcome the issue by factoring in the change in directory in your commands.

Answer (score 0):

I may run in a similar case. My code looks something like this, e.g. at D:\test\myscript.ps1:

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

#pos1: before invoke-sqlcmd
Get-Location # will return D:\test
Invoke-Sqlcmd ...
#pos2: afer invokes-sqlcmd
Get-Location 

Test-Path -path <UNC-Path> # the <UNC-Path> absolutely exists.
```

My problem:

- when I execute this script in a PowerShell session, the `Test-Path` returns True.
- when I configure this script to execute as an SQL Server Agent job step in this same server, the `Test-Path` always return False.
  My step configure is

  powershell -file "D:\test\myscript.ps1"

In the log from SQL Server Agent job step, the `Get-Location` at pos2 returns "SQLSERVER:\"

I worked around by using `Set-Location $PScriptRoot` after the `Invoke-SqlCmd` and the `Test-Path` returns True as expected.

So can anyone please explain why `Invoke-SqlCmd` changes the location and how this affect the `Test-Path`.

Thank you.