# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd working directory

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a Powershell script in a folder structure like this:

```
 ── Versions/
    └── v025/
        └── v025.sql
        Update.ps1
        RunScript.sql
```

Update.ps1 file has the following command

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile "./RunScript.sql" -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Username $user -Password $pass
```

RunScript.sql has the following:

```
:r v025\v025.sql
```

The result message of the execution is:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd : Cannot find path 'v025\v025.sql' because it does not exist.
```

Why is this happening? The file is located correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try fully qualifying the path to your script as a first test, check the direction of the slashes in case they are being treated as escapes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried that and works as expected.

Comment: OK - I'm not farmiliar with the SQL syntax contained in your script `:r v025\v025.sql` but generally I'd be thinking that paths executed in SQL queries usualy relate to the SERVER (say for backup / disk operations etc) since the query is sent remotely to the server and executed there. If it works with an absolute path, and this is a local server instance.... that could be why?

Comment: Well, this was working in a bat script. But we need to migrate to PowerShell and now we have this error message.

Comment: What does `:r` do?

Comment: Runs the SQL file

Comment: Ok, I see - Invoke-SqlCmd is compatible with SQLCMD syntax. All I can suggest then is a working directory/ home directory mismatch.

Comment: Looks like some other people htting issues with directory changing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273440/why-working-directory-is-changing-when-executing-invoke-sqlcmd and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/01355ccd-4c3c-4238-995d-2c890eb25f81/powershell-invokesqlcmd-does-not-go-back-to-working-folder-in-script?forum=sqltools perhaps something here will help?

Comment: I've already checked this links with no luck. 
I don't know why a bat script works fine, but PowerShell does not recognize the path.

Comment: Isn't `v025` located in the `Versions` directory? Whether the command is being called from the context of Update.ps1 or RunScript.sql, I would expect it to be `:r Versions\v025\v025.sql`. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @DanWilson I think you are spot on. I had looked for a path error but the formatting of the bullet list kind of hid that for me. This is probably the answer OP.

Comment: Edited the formatting of the file system sample to make it more obvious. Path to the script, relative to RunScript.sql is: `.\Versions\v025\v025.sql` as Dan said.

Comment: I'm sorry, the bullet list is wrong. RunScript.sql is inside Versions folder.

Answer (score 1):

*After searching around a lot in several threads, I have finally found the solution to this issue.*

Typically, Powershell runs commands in the current location, which you can get with `Get-Location`. However, for some reason, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` runs in the `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory`. This typically sets to the path where the terminal process is starting, but does not follow when you do `Set-Location`/`cd`.

To make it so that `Invoke-Sqlcmd` executes in a specific directory, set the `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory` to that location. Below is an example which sets this to the current location/folder (assuming that you want to execute from there) and then sets it back after the command is finished:

```
$OriginalDirectory = [Environment]::CurrentDirectory
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
Invoke-Sqlcmd <your parameters here>
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $OriginalDirectory
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming windows, you might want to try using .\v025\v025.sql

Also, I could be wrong but I think
Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile "./RunScript.sql"

should be

Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile ".\RunScript.sql"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. 
This gives the same error:
Invoke-SqlCmd : Cannot find path '.\v025\v025.sql' because it does not exist

Comment: I think it's because RunScript.sql is running on the server, and since v025.sql isn't on the server (or at least in a relative path to where you're running it) I don't think it's going to work. - Can you make your powershell script just run the v025.sql as a separate invoke-sqlcmd?

Comment: Yes, I can run this and runs as expected. But is not what I need.
I need to run RunScript.sql, this SQL has several r: commands inside, and also every v0x/x0x.sql file has a few r: commands also.